# MySQL Workbench or PHP MyAdmin where is the EER Diagram?

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench, entity-relationship

I haven't used MySQL workbench in a few years, and the documentation I've found is not updated for version 6. I'm looking for instructions on creating an EER diagram from my existing schema. How would I do that in the latest version of MySQL workbench (6.0 or later)?

I also have access to phpMyAdmin 4.0 and could do it from there with some pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating an EER diagram from an existing schema is called *reverse engineering*. In MySQL Workbench you simply start from the homescreen and open menu -> Database -> Reverse Engineer...

This will ask you for a connection to a server and, once connnected, will allow you to select all schemas on that server you want to create a representation from. Simply follow the wizard further until it is done. Provided there are no errors you should get a new model with all the selected content in it.